# Why degree is the sum of local degree?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, solution-verification

[image]

The above picture is from Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, pp.135-136.

Why is my argument wrong?

Consider the diagram in the picture above. We know that the four red-boxed groups are all $\Bbb Z$ and that the whole diagram is commutative. Now we only consider the four maps, as indicated by red arrows. Since the vertical two red arrows are isomorphisms, we have a commutative diagram of the form:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Bbb Z  @>{}>> \Bbb Z \\
@V{\cong}VV @V{\cong}VV \\
\Bbb Z @>{}>> \Bbb Z \end{CD}

Now we conclude that the local degree at $x_i$ equals the degree of $f$ up to sign.

Comment: You can have a try to prove that your "commutative" diagram is really "commutative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram does not commute. In short, the diagram in Hatcher has the form $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
&&\mathbb{Z}\\
&@V{\alpha}VV\\
\mathbb{Z}@<{\pi}<<\mathbb{Z}^m@>\gamma>>\mathbb{Z}\\
&@A{\beta}AA\\
&&\mathbb{Z}
\end{CD}

in which  $\alpha:1\mapsto(0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)$ ($1$ in the $i$th place) and $\beta:1\mapsto(1,\cdots ,1)$, and $\pi$ is the projection to the $i$ th coordinate. For sure, you have $\pi\circ\alpha=\pi\circ\beta$, but there is no reason to expect that $\gamma \circ \alpha=\gamma\circ\beta$. Take $m=2,\gamma(m,n)=10m+20n$, for example.