# Doubt about Hatcher's proof of degree calculation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Proposition 2.30 shows that the degree of a map $S^n \to S^n$ is the sum of its local degrees across a finite set $\{x_i\}$ that is the preimage of a point $y$. The definition of the local degree and the proof of the proposition use the commutative diagram below. [image]
My question: why can't we follow the outer isomorphisms to get the degree of the bottom horizontal map? All of the outer vertical maps send generators to generators because they are isomorphisms, so why is it that the degree of the bottom map is not the degree of the top map? I think I'm overlooking something silly but can't figure it out. Effectively the same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507866/why-degree-is-the-sum-of-local-degree) but I do not find the answer convincing because it ignores the outer maps.

Comment: When you say "the outer maps", you mean the vertical maps on the right side of the diagram, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "follow the outer isomorphisms". You know that the (different) maps denoted by $f_*$ are not necessarily isomorphisms.

Comment: I mean the vertical maps on the left and right side of the diagram, i.e., the relativisation and excision on both sides of the diagram.

Comment: @AnginaSeng yes I do, I meant that the bottom $f_*$ should be the same as the composition of all the other maps on the periphery of this diagram, of which only the top $f_*$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: I think you are imagining the diagram without the central term and its associated maps. In general, that diagram **won't** commute.

Comment: @AnginaSeng why not? Every triangle/square in the above diagram commutes, so shouldn't any subset of the diagram also commute?

Comment: See Ken's answer in the linked question. Really this commutative diagram is two commutative diagrams, one consisting of the first two rows and on of the last two rows. Try chasing an element round the diagram to see if your "outer terms" diagram commutes. You'll find you won't be able to.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I see. So the diagram is not a commutative diagram, it is merely a diagram showing the domain and target of some maps, where some of the maps commute.

Comment: The title of your question is "Doubt about Hatcher's proof of degree calculation". What are your doubts? Whether the proof is correct? Whether it is too complicated?

Comment: @abhi01nat The two triangles and two squares shown commute; other routes through the diagram may not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Hatcher has considered his diagram he proves Proposition 2.30 which says that $\deg f = \sum_i \deg f \mid_{x_i}$. Commutativity of the "outer isomorphism diagram"

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)  @>{(f_i)_*}>> H_n(V,V -y) \\
@V{\approx}VV @V{\approx}VV \\
H_n(S^n) @>{f_*}>> H_n(S^n) \end{CD}

would mean that $\deg f = \deg f \mid_{x_i}$ *for each* $i$. In that case the above degree-formula couldn't be correct. This is a priori no argument against commutativity - perhaps the degree formula is wrong? Let us come to this point later.

What Hatcher is doing with his diagram are two things:

1. He shows that $A = H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)$ and $B =  H_n(V,V -y)$ are infinite cyclic groups. For this purpose he wouldn't have needed the whole diagram, he only uses excision and the exact sequence of a pair to establish explicit isomorphisms $\phi : A \to H_n(S^n)$ and $\psi : B \to H_n(S^n)$. Thus $(f_i)_* : A \to B$ is a homomorphism between infinite cyclic groups. To describe this map, we have to make a choice of generators $g_A$ for $A$ and $g_B$ for $B$. These choices are in general *independent* since normally $A \ne B$. Only if $U_i = V$ and $x_i = y$ we have $A = B$ and one choice is sufficient. Based on our choices we get $(f_i)_*(g_A) = n g_B$ for some factor $n \in \mathbb Z$. Since also  $-g_A$ and $-g_B$ are generators, we do not get a *canonical* factor $n = n((f_i)_*)$ - without an explicit choice of generators it is determined only up to sign. And here $\phi, \psi$ enter: To the map $\psi (f_i)_* \phi^{-1} : H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$ we can associate a canonical factor in $\mathbb Z$ because we may choose one generator of $H_n(S^n)$. This factor is denoted by $\deg f \mid_{x_i}$.
2. The full diagram is used in the proof of Proposition 2.30. Have a look at the proof!

Let us finally come to the outer isomorphism diagram. In Example 2.31  Hatcher shows how to construct a map $f : S^n \to S^n$ of any degree $k \in \mathbb Z$. However, $\deg f \mid_{x_i} = \pm 1$, thus in general $\deg f \ne \deg f \mid_{x_i}$ - the outer isomorphism diagram does not commute in that case.

Although we have found explicit examples in which the outer isomorphism diagram does not commute, an obvious *heuristic argument*  why we cannot expect commutativity is this:

1. The map $p_i : H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y)) \to H_n(S^n,S^n-x_i)$ is in general not an isomorphism. $H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ is a free abelian group with $m$ generators, where $m$ is the number of points in $f^{-1}(y)$.
2. $p_i$ goes into the "wrong direction" which makes it impossible for $m > 1$ to show via standard diagram chasing that the outer isomorphism diagram commutes. It only works for $m=1$ where we have $p_i = id$.