# degree formula $\deg(f) = \sum_i \deg(f)|x_i$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading Hatcher's algebraic topology book,there is a theorem for local degree as follows in Proposition 2.30  p136:

$$\deg(f) = \sum_i \deg_{x_i}f$$

Where $x_i \in f^{-1}(y)$ that $\deg_{x_i}$ is the local degree.

which is proved using the following diagram:
[image]

In the book we use the fact that $p_i\circ j(1) = 1$ thanks to the isomorphism in the lower triangle.the proof stated as below:

Proof: By excision, the central term $H_{n}\left(S^{n}, S^{n}-f^{-1}(y)\right)$ in the preceding diagram is the direct sum of the groups $H_{n}\left(U_{i}, U_{i}-x_{i}\right) \approx \mathbb{Z}$, with $k_{i}$ the inclusion of the $i^{t h}$ summand and $p_{i}$ the projection onto the $i^{t h}$ summand. Identifying the outer groups in the diagram with $\mathbb{Z}$ as before, commutativity of the lower triangle says that $p_{i} j(1)=1$, hence $j(1)=(1, \cdots, 1)=\sum_{i} k_{i}(1)$. Commutativity of the upper square says that the middle $f_{*}$ takes $k_{i}(1)$ to $\operatorname{deg} f \mid x_{i}$, hence the sum $\sum_{i} k_{i}(1)=j(1)$ is taken to $\sum_{i} \operatorname{deg} f \mid x_{i}$. Commutativity of the lower square then gives the formula $\operatorname{deg} f=\sum_{i} \operatorname{deg} f \mid x_{i}$

**The question is the isomorphism only maps generator to generator,can we let $p_i\circ j(1) = -1$?**

Comment: The crux is what he means by "Identifying the outer groups in the diagram with $\mathbb{Z}$ as before". These identifications, described at the top of the page, come precisely from identifying these groups with one another through the isomorphisms in this diagram, so once a generator of $H_n(S^n)$ is chosen, the generators of the other groups are the images of this generator under the respective isomorphisms and the isomorphisms get identified with the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$ tautologically.

Comment: thank you Thorgott,I get the point.

Comment: Also look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3832079 .